# NAVICAT - I cant DATA TRANSFER my Stored Procedures and Views

Tags: mysql, database, navicat

I am trying to use DATA TRANSFER to transfer the remote DB to a localhost Virtual Machine. The database name on the VM is the same name as the remote DB.

My problem is that the CHECKBOXES for VIEWS/STORED PROCEDURES are DIMMED and I cant select my SP's.

Please help!

Comment: If I understand data transfer moves data, not objects. To move objects, try Schema Comparer tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/), there are also data Comparer.

Answer (score 3):

SPs and Views are not data, they are part of the DB structure. Navicat Premium for MySQL has an option called Structure Synchronisation.  It's in the tools menu.  From there you can find options to compare Tables, Views, Functions and Events. After making a comparison of your DB, Navicat creates SQL to recreate those objects on the remote server. You can tick which of the statements you want to run if you only want to synchronise some of the objects.

Comment: *Structure Synchronization* is also available in Navicat Standard at the time of writing.